How can I generate and serve a file from webroot with Azure App Service?
I've deployed a legacy ASP.NET app to Azure App Service and now I would like to dynamically generate a file in code and then serve it from wwwroot. I.e. I need files to be accessible under https://my-appservice.com/PDF/file.pdf., for example.
However, with Azure App Service, I cannot write to the wwwroot directory, because I'm getting a permission denied error. I confirmed this by using Azure App Service console: I also cannot cd into wwwroot and touch files there, because it errors out.
So my initial idea was to write to Path.GetTempPath() which ends up resolved as being outside the web directory, in D:/local/temp, and then use the path mapping configuration setting in Azure to map that path to a virtual directory. Well, it turned out that I can only map physical paths that start with site or mounts.
So, since my directory structure after deployment is as follows, D:/home/site/wwwroot/, I thought in code I'd try the following to get the path I want to write my files to:
var path = Server.MapPath("~/..")
Which I hoped would lead them to end up in the /site directory, which I could then map to a virtual directory (/PDF) and serve the files from there.
However, it turns out I cannot use ".." to go outside wwwroot.
Overall, I feel like there must be something I'm missing. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?
I understand I can always use Azure SDK for blob storage and upload there, but what I would like to achieve seems way easier; it's just I don't understand why I can't do that.

The Web App is sandboxed to prevent directory traversal. You won't be able to write to most locations outside wwwroot in code, or via console in Kudu.
You were on a legitimate track using the temp directory, but you can't serve files from it using a virtual directory. You need to copy the file to a physical path inside wwwroot.

Create a physical folder in wwwroot.
mkdir D:/home/site/wwwroot/PDF
In your code, specify D:/local/temp as your PDF output directory.
Move the PDF to your physical directory.

var tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "yourpdf.pdf");
var permanentPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), "yourpdf.pdf");

// Generate your PDF and save it to the temp path

// Move the file to the permanent path
File.Move(tempPath, permanentPath);


Serve the file as /PDF/yourpdf.pdf

Your PDF directory will obviously grow in size over time. You can combat this by creating a cleanup WebJob:

Create a PowerShell script named ClearPDFDirectory.ps1:

Remove-Item -Path "D:\home\site\wwwroot\Files\*" -Recurse -Force


Add the script to your WebJob:


Create a new WebJob in your Azure App Service.
Upload the ClearPDFDirectory.ps1 script to the WebJob.


Schedule the WebJob:


In the Azure portal, navigate to your WebJob.
Configure the schedule using a CRON expression (e.g., 0 0 * * * to run daily at midnight).


Hey, thanks. I've just tried that but I'm now getting: Unable to find the specified file error when trying to move the file. I called File.Exists on the tempPath, and it does get created, but attempting to move the file to the wwwroot/Files results with the above error. The permanent path also seems valid when I log it (C:\home\site\wwwroot\Files\ae387a90-551d-4b3f-a8e2-7ac933996012.pdf). I'm wondering whether that's to do with the type of deployment, with the RUN_FROM_PACKAGE being set to 1?

@colma Did you create the Files directory already? In the steps I made a small mistake. I used /PDF in the mkdir command, but /Files in the code. Just check you have the correct ones. I went along with using the ephemeral temp disk because, generally, you'll get better performance. You may want to try negating it though and generating your PDFs directly to /PDF or /Files

Hey, thanks. Yes, I made sure the paths were correct. I believe the issue was due to us using the zip-package deployment. From this Microsoft article: 'Instead, the ZIP package itself gets mounted directly as the read-only wwwroot directory.'. We needed to create PDF files to later serve their URIs on the server as an src for an iFrame. Instead, we worked around this by setting the src to bytes.
